# access method in a object via pointer cpp - vscode error

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, syntax

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
class Bird{
  public:
    int A;
    Bird(int Y){A = Y;}
    int retrieve(){return A;}
} ;
int main(){
Bird * C  =new Bird(6);
cout<< C.retrieve()<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

I can't access the object's retrieve() method which is pointed by C pointer(the object is pointed by C). Is there any way to do this . Please let me know.I use vscode V1.29.1

Comment: Instead of `C.retrieve()`, try `C->retrieve()`.

Comment: @Blaze It didn't work out :(

Comment: @Nipunachandimal "_It didn't work out_" Why? Did you receive an error? What error was it?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I'm using vscode. It showed me this.g++: error: pointer: No such file or directory
g++: error: _error.cpp: No such file or directory
g++: error: _error: No such file or directory

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.062 seconds

Comment: Sure seems to work out [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef5c53e2131ebd1d). You seem to just have a configuration problem.

Comment: This is ridiculous. This is something that will be covered in an introductory text. Trying to learn C++ by asking questions about each language feature in turn won't be fun for anyone.

Comment: c++ is difficult to self-teach. You should read [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to get you started. It's not practical to learn c++ by trial-and-error or by asking questions about the basic topics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are instantiating an `Bird` instance on the heap and store a pointer to that object in a variable named `C`. Pointers must be dereferenced before accessing data members or member functions, i.e.

```
std::cout << C->retrieve() << "\n";

// or, as @PeteBecker has pointed out in the comments
std::cout << (*C).retrieve() << "\n";
```

Also, don't forget to

```
delete C;
```

or even better: use the `<memory>` header and `std::make_unique`, which frees you from the necessity to manually clean up the pointer.

```
#include <memory>

auto C = std::make_unique<Bird>(6);

std::cout<< C->retrieve() << "\n";
```

Comment: Re: "store a reference to that object in a pointer" -- **reference** has a specific meaning in C++, and this is not it. The code stores the **address** of that object in the pointer. +1.

Comment: And just for completeness, `(*C).retrieve()` also works. `->` is much clearer.

Comment: This didn't work for me . ERROR  IS "
g++: error: pointer: No such file or directory
g++: error: _error.cpp: No such file or directory
g++: error: _error: No such file or directory"

Comment: @Nipunachandimal It sounds like your problem has nothing to do with your code. Your project file or environment is not properly configured.

Comment: @PeteBecker Thanks for the suggestion, I fixed it.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux  you are correct . When  I compile it using codeblocks the error gone away . Thanks for your kind full support !!